What is a generalized algorithm to find five $z$-bit words for the inverse of $\theta$ function in the Keccak-$f$ permutation?
This implementation of the inverse of the Keccak-$f$ permutation contains five 64-bit words (called “inversePositions64” in the code) for the inverse of $\theta$ function:
0xDE26BC4D789AF134,
0x09AF135E26BC4D78,
0xEBC4D789AF135E26,
0x7135E26BC4D789AF,
0xCD789AF135E26BC4.

What is a self-contained generalized algorithm (in the C-like pseudocode) for a function that, given a parameter $z \in \{1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, \ldots\},$ outputs five corresponding $z$-bit words for the inverse of $\theta$?
